# Directadmin error nameserver configuration

Tags: directadmin

**Can you explain what is this. and what can I do now. In diractadmin web control panel. Please reply as soon as possible.**

Added record ns1.brijmart.com. A 104.197.176.21 to satisfy mybrijkart.com. NS ns1.brijmart.com.
Added record ns2.brijmart.com. A 104.197.176.21 to satisfy brijmart.com. NS ns2.brijmart.com.
Please check the zone for brijmart.com to ensure the nameserver A records are correct.
User added to named.conf file successfully

Comment: If you could add a little bit explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I want to help you, but I need some informations.

This message may be information only.
Could you please login in your account at the "user level" and in Account Manager >> DNS Settings paste the information here? (please hide your ips and domain)

Are you responsible for this server?
Do you have access to the Admin user? If so, are the primary DNS(ns1 e ns2) configured correctly?

I appreciate any additional information you can send